# Encryption/Decryption using AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding

Tags: php, android, python, encryption, cryptography

I need help in encrypting with AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding. I need the same results like [here](http://www.txtwizard.net/crypto).

Comment: Hi, please show us your code/what you have tried. That way, we can help you out faster.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais I tried https://github.com/gunnzhao/AES-CBC-PKCS7Padding-/blob/master/AesCrypter.php this code.

Comment: Put your code (the _actual_ code that _you_ are using) directly in the question.

Comment: @PatrickQ My codes are not working. I want help for new code or library

Comment: @user1318741, yes, your code is not working. So, put your code in the post so that we can see where it went wrong and help you fix it. Are you using a library in your code?

Comment: @user1318741 That's not how it works here. Requesting a library or other third-party code is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais Updated, this one is i used.

Comment: Is this *your* actual code that you use to encrypt text and not just the library you use?

Comment: That is simply a class file. By itself, it does nothing. You need to show how _you_ personally implemented it, along with what you _expected_ the result to be, and what the result _actually_ was.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais yes i use this code. But this is not gave same result.

Comment: Like what @PatrickQ said, it's just a class file you use. How did you use the class file in *your* code to encrypt text?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais updated again.

Comment: Okay, good, we're getting somewhere.  Now, why are you trying to produce a specific encrypted value? That doesn't really make sense. As long as you can encrypt plain-text and then decrypted the encrypted text back to the original, why do you care what the encrypted value is?

Comment: @PatrickQ Because the application is encrypted in this way. I need to decrypt responses.

Comment: @user1318741, I guess the implementation you got did not implement IVs. That is prolly what is causing it to give you a different result than expected.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais i think same but i cant find how to add iv this class.

Comment: I guess you have to read the AES specs to understand how to add IV.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais My code shows exactly how the IV is used in CBC.

Comment: Please don't remove your question like that after it receives an answer. Your question and its answers are supposed to be useful to future readers, not just yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do this task using the popular [`cryptography`](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/) library. This code was adapted from their documentation. It uses the data, key, and IV that were initially given in the question.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode

backend = default_backend()
padder = padding.PKCS7(128).padder()
unpadder = padding.PKCS7(128).unpadder()

data = b'demo'
data = padder.update(data) + padder.finalize()
key = b64decode('HJkPmTz+uY7wd0p1+w//DABgbvPq9/230RwEG2sJ9mo=')
iv = b64decode('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==')

cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
ct = encryptor.update(data) + encryptor.finalize()
ct_out = b64encode(ct)
print(ct_out)

decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
plain = decryptor.update(ct) + decryptor.finalize()
plain = unpadder.update(plain) + unpadder.finalize()
print(plain)
```

**output**

```
b'W2FEImF2qrAjaJ/LV+bgQA=='
b'demo'
```

---

Just for fun, here's an implementation that requires no 3rd-party packages.
Normally, one wouldn't do this sort of thing, since the first rule of crypto is "Don't roll your own crypto!". But here's some AES code I wrote as part of the Cryptopals challenge. ;) It does AES ECB encoding by directly calling the standard OpenSSL library via ctypes, and then uses that to perform CBC encryption / decryption.

This code was developed and tested on a Linux system running Python 3.6.0, but it should also run on Windows. I assume it will also run correctly on OSX.

```
import os
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode
from ctypes import *

AES_MAXNR = 14
AES_BLOCK_SIZE = 16

DECODE = 0
ENCODE = 1

class AES_KEY(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("rd_key", c_long * 4 *(AES_MAXNR + 1)),
        ("rounds", c_int),
    ]

crypto = cdll.LoadLibrary("libeay32.dll" if os.name == "nt" else "libssl.so")

# Function prototypes
AES_set_encrypt_key = crypto.AES_set_encrypt_key
AES_set_encrypt_key.restype = c_int
# userKey, bits, key
AES_set_encrypt_key.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_int, POINTER(AES_KEY)]

AES_set_decrypt_key = crypto.AES_set_decrypt_key
AES_set_decrypt_key.restype = c_int
# userKey, bits, key
AES_set_decrypt_key.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_int, POINTER(AES_KEY)]

AES_ecb_encrypt = crypto.AES_ecb_encrypt
AES_ecb_encrypt.restype = None
#in, out, key, enc(1=encode, 0=decode) 
AES_ecb_encrypt.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p, POINTER(AES_KEY), c_int]

set_key = (AES_set_decrypt_key, AES_set_encrypt_key)

def set_aes_key(key, encode):
    ''' Create an AES encoding or decoding key '''
    keylen = len(key)
    valid = {16, 24, 32}
    if keylen not in valid:
        msg = f'Key length must be one of {valid}, not {keylen}'
        raise ValueError(msg)

    aes_key = AES_KEY()
    rc = set_key[encode](c_char_p(key), keylen * 8, byref(aes_key))
    if rc != 0:
        # I don't think we can get here...
        raise ValueError('Error generating AES key', rc)
    return aes_key

def aes_ecb(block, aes_key, encode):
    ''' Encrypt or decrypt a single block '''
    outbuff = create_string_buffer(AES_BLOCK_SIZE)
    AES_ecb_encrypt(c_char_p(block), outbuff, byref(aes_key), encode)
    return outbuff.raw

def PKCS7_pad(data):
    padsize = AES_BLOCK_SIZE - len(data) % AES_BLOCK_SIZE
    return data + bytes([padsize]) * padsize

def PKCS7_unpad(data):
    offset = data[-1]
    return data[:-offset]

def xor_bytes(a, b):
    size = len(a)
    a = int.from_bytes(a, 'big')
    b = int.from_bytes(b, 'big')
    return (a ^ b).to_bytes(size, 'big')

def aes_cbc_encode(data, key, iv):
    ekey = set_aes_key(key, ENCODE)

    data = PKCS7_pad(data)
    cipher = []
    for block in zip(*[iter(data)] * AES_BLOCK_SIZE):
        block = bytes(block)
        coded = aes_ecb(xor_bytes(iv, block), ekey, ENCODE)
        cipher.append(coded)
        iv = coded

    return b''.join(cipher)

def aes_cbc_decode(data, key, iv):
    dkey = set_aes_key(key, DECODE)

    plain = []
    for block in zip(*[iter(data)] * AES_BLOCK_SIZE):
        block = bytes(block)
        decoded = aes_ecb(block, dkey, DECODE)
        plain.append(xor_bytes(iv, decoded))
        iv = block

    plain[-1] = PKCS7_unpad(plain[-1])
    return b''.join(plain)

# Test

data = b'demo'
key = b64decode('HJkPmTz+uY7wd0p1+w//DABgbvPq9/230RwEG2sJ9mo=')
iv = b64decode('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==')
cipher = aes_cbc_encode(data, key, iv)
out = b64encode(cipher)
print(out)

plain = aes_cbc_decode(cipher, key, iv)
print(plain)
```

**output**

```
b'W2FEImF2qrAjaJ/LV+bgQA=='
b'demo'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I try right away.

Comment: @user1318741 My pleasure!

Comment: Awesome code, but wouldn't it be much simpler/better to use [pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/)? Or is the OP not permitted to use third party libs?

Comment: @t.m.adam  Sure, normally one would use a crypto package to do this, and the resulting code would be more compact and easier to read. But it's handy to be able to do stuff without having to install a 3rd party package, and as I said, I'd already written and tested these functions, so it was easy for me to combine them into the above code. Also, my code clearly shows how CBC is built from ECB, which is good to know.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that (CBC from ECB), although you could have done the same with pycryptodome's AES class in ECB mode. Again, the code looks great, I was just curious to know why you chose this method.

Comment: Hello this code using to much cpu is it normal? @PM2Ring

Comment: @user1318741 It uses a _little_ more CPU than code which uses a proper crypto package, because it's doing the padding with Python code, and it's doing the CBC stuff with a Python loop that calls the ECB library code, rather than using a CBC library call, which can do that loop with compiled code. But all the AES number crunching _is_ being done by the OpenSSL library, using compiled code. If you are processing a lot of data, that will chew up a lot of CPU, that's unavoidable.

Comment: Okey i found library thanks.

Comment: @user1318741 See the updated answer.