# How to pass a C struct with arrays and variables to OpenCL kernel using PyOpenCL

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, opencl, pyopencl

So, I have to pass some data to a OpenCL kernel using PyOpenCL or some workaround using Python. The data is readed in the kernel-side as a struct and I can't change the kernel cuz it is working fine and is a part of a much bigger project that my code must work with.

The kernel looks like that:

```
typedef struct VglClStrEl{ 
    float data[VGL_ARR_CLSTREL_SIZE];
    int ndim;
    int shape[VGL_ARR_SHAPE_SIZE];
    int offset[VGL_ARR_SHAPE_SIZE];
    int size;
} VglClStrEl;

typedef struct VglClShape{ 
    int ndim;
    int shape[VGL_ARR_SHAPE_SIZE];
    int offset[VGL_ARR_SHAPE_SIZE];
    int size;
} VglClShape;

__kernel void kernel(__global unsigned char* img_input, 
                     __global unsigned char* img_output,  
                     __constant VglClShape* img_shape,
                     __constant VglClStrEl* window)
{

    // do what is needed

}
```

So, as you can see, the VglClShape and VglClStrEl structures, have different type arrays and static-bitsize variables.

The [1] workaround supports structs with only one type arrays(or I tragically failed to get a way to do it with multiple array types).

The [2] workaround is the PyOpenCL documentation reference for how pass Python data to a OpenCL kernel struct. This approach don't support arrays at all.

So, how can I pass the python data as the OpenCL kernel can read? I already have all the data on Python-side, and I just need to know how to pass it from the Python to the kernel.

Before you ask: I am using Python 3 and **I CAN NOT CHANGE THE KERNEL**.

And yes, the array sizes are static. You can assume something like that:

```
VGL_ARR_CLSTREL_SIZE=256;
VGL_ARR_SHAPE_SIZE=20;
```

[1] [Passing struct with pointer members to OpenCL kernel using PyOpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635898/passing-struct-with-pointer-members-to-opencl-kernel-using-pyopencl)

[2] https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/howto.html#how-to-use-struct-types-with-pyopencl

Comment: Can you use the standard `ctypes` module?

Comment: @PM2Ring As a know, ctypes is a Python foreign library to use C things on Python. What I need to do is the inverse: pass Python data to OpenCL in a way it understands (paying attention to memory allocation symmetry between both). Can I use ctypes to do something like that?

Comment: I don't know OpenCL, but I've used `ctypes` to interact with the OpenSSL library. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26878137/4014959) for an example. And the final codeblock [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50063211/4014959) has another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hackish way to do this that requires some tedious byte wrangling. Presumably you are OK with deploying a small OpenCL probing kernel? (PyOpenCL does this under the hood for some ops in any case)

The basic idea is to:

- find out how the OpenCL device aligns all the elements of your structs by running a single instance kernel
- create a numpy byte array to match the size of the OpenCL struct
- byte-wise copy each element of your Python struct into this array
- when invoking your unchangeable OpenCL kernel, pass this array via a bag of bytes buffer

The following kernel does the job:

```
__kernel void get_struct_sizes( __global uint *struct_sizes )
{
    const uint global_id = get_global_id(0u)+get_global_id(1u)*get_global_size(0u);
    VglClStrEl vgclstrel;
    VglClShape vgclshape;
    uint offset;

    printf("In GPU (probing):\n Kernel instance = %d\n", global_id);

    if (global_id==0) {
        offset = (uint)&(vgclstrel.data);
        struct_sizes[0] = (uint)sizeof(vgclstrel);
        struct_sizes[1] = (uint)&(vgclstrel.ndim)-offset;
        struct_sizes[2] = (uint)&(vgclstrel.shape)-offset;
        struct_sizes[3] = (uint)&(vgclstrel.offset)-offset;
        struct_sizes[4] = (uint)&(vgclstrel.size)-offset;
        offset = (uint)&(vgclshape.ndim);
        struct_sizes[5] = (uint)sizeof(vgclshape);
        struct_sizes[6] = (uint)&(vgclshape.shape)-offset;
        struct_sizes[7] = (uint)&(vgclshape.offset)-offset;
        struct_sizes[8] = (uint)&(vgclshape.size)-offset;
    }
    return;
}
```

Execute this kernel and return `struct_sizes` into `vgclshape_sizes`, create this array:

```
img_shape  = np.zeros((vgclshape_sizes[0]), dtype=np.uint8)
```

and copy into it what you need:

```
def copy_into_byte_array(value, byte_array, offset):
        for i,b in enumerate(np.ndarray.tobytes(value)):
            byte_array[i+offset] = b
copy_into_byte_array(ndim,   img_shape, 0) 
copy_into_byte_array(shape,  img_shape, vgclshape_sizes[1]) 
copy_into_byte_array(offset, img_shape, vgclshape_sizes[2]) 
copy_into_byte_array(size,   img_shape, vgclshape_sizes[3])
```

I've skipped some steps here; filling them in you'll find this approach works. I was able to pass a demo struct to a dummy copy of your inviolate kernel.

I would be interested to hear if there are more elegant ways to do any/all of these steps. I would also expect there will be problems with endianness etc that would otherwise be transparent. With luck you can work around them.

Comment: How did you passed the bag of bytes to the kernel? When I try to pass the byte bag, I get the error clSetKernelArg failed: INVALID_ARG_SIZE

Comment: Look in here:
https://github.com/cstarknyc/PyPlayground/tree/master/Pass_Struct

...but basically:

   `struct_sizes  = np.zeros(9, dtype=np.uint32)`
    `struct_sizes_buffer = cl.Buffer(cl_state.context, COPY_WRITE, 
                                        hostbuf=struct_sizes)
    buffer_list = [struct_sizes_buffer]
    cl_state.kernel.set_args(*buffer_list)
    cl_state.kernel.set_scalar_arg_dtypes( [None]*len(buffer_list) )
    cl_state.event = cl.enqueue_nd_range_kernel(cl_state.queue, cl_state.kernel, global_size, local_size)`

Comment: Finally got it working as expected. Thank you very much by your help Colin!

Comment: Cant yet. I don't have the 15 points of reputation. WHen I get them I'll vote you up