# AES encryption differences in Ruby vs Python

Tags: python, ruby, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to encrypt a message using AES-256-CBC but I get different behavior in Ruby and Python versions. It seems like Python's AES encryption does not add a suffix.

```
require 'base64'
require 'aescrypt'

key = "z\r}\xE6\xB5\xB0P:\x80D@+\x96S\xAB (\x87\xDD#3x\xB9\xF3\xB4\xE7*qTKz\xC1"
iv = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
data = "\xC7u\xE7\xB7W\xED\xE60\xCD\n\xA1\x11;\xD1\x02f\x1A\xB3\x88)\xCAR\xA6B*\xB7\x82\x86/&\x86F"

Base64.encode64(AESCrypt.encrypt_data(data, key, iv, "AES-256-CBC"))

=> "ldB7M0nr+FP6I9NiogtvysUFfUC2vIt6Hj7cwzEiUEal76Cpyc+x6RTiHgkq\n6j7n\n"
```

Whereas in Python using `cryptography`:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import base64
backend = default_backend()

key = "z\r}\xE6\xB5\xB0P:\x80D@+\x96S\xAB (\x87\xDD#3x\xB9\xF3\xB4\xE7*qTKz\xC1"
iv = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
data = "\xC7u\xE7\xB7W\xED\xE60\xCD\n\xA1\x11;\xD1\x02f\x1A\xB3\x88)\xCAR\xA6B*\xB7\x82\x86/&\x86F"

cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
ct = encryptor.update(data) + encryptor.finalize()
base64.b64encode(ct)

=> 'ldB7M0nr+FP6I9NiogtvysUFfUC2vIt6Hj7cwzEiUEY='
```

You can see the encrypted text produced by Ruby library has extra 16 bytes. I have Java code as well which produces exact same ciphertext as Ruby version. Python code is behaving oddly. How can I change the Python code so that it produces the same ciphertext?

Comment: It looks like you're using Python 2. Is that correct?

Comment: I just remembered I wrote an answer for AES CBC using the cryptography package a few months ago. You may find it helpful. Note the PKCS7 padding. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50063211/4014959

Answer (score 2):

A friend pointed out the problem: the `encrypt` method requires padded data:

```
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
ct = encryptor.update(pad(data,16)) + encryptor.finalize()
```

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer by now.